# Apache Lucene ignores months and days in date range search expression

Tags: lucene

I try to query Apache Lucene index which is built using a database table that contains a date column and my query refers to this very column. In Luke the search expression I use is as follows:

```
column_name:[yyyy-MM-dd TO yyyy-MM-dd]
```

The results returned are records which do not have dates (in the queried column) with the year in the start value or older and the ones that do have year after the year in the start value up to the year in the end value. So if I write column_name:[2011-05-22 TO 2015-09-03] - I will get records with the dates in the column with years 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015.

However, the results will not be precise according to the search expression - the month and days value will be ignored. No matter what month and day I will set up - the search will result in records being returned with dates across each of the searched year (from 01.01 to 31.12).

The issue occurs if I use another date format like:

```
column_name:[yyyyMMdd TO yyyyMMdd]
```

I am looking to find what might be causing this? Is this a matter of date formatting while indexing? Or is this a matter of date format in the search expression?

I should add for more clarity that the search expression:

```
column_name:"yyyy-MM-dd"
```

will return records as exepcted - so with the date included in the expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analysis is the issue.

When you index, your dates are getting split into three terms: "2011", "05", and "22". Any *one* of the terms can be matched against a range query, but not all three. So for `[2011-05-22 TO 2015-09-03]`, the term 2011 does not fall lexicographically in that range, while 2012, 2013, 2014 and 2015 all do. For another example, if you searched for `[1999-01-01 TO 2000-01-01]`, you would also find all dates on the twentieth of a month, because 20 falls within that lexicographic range.

Since this field is just a date, you should just avoid tokenizing it. Use `StringField` instead of a `TextField`, and re-index.

Comment: Changing date format from yyyy-MM-dd to yyyyMMdd actually helped - I was able to query with the precision to a day as I wanted, but it did require re-indexing.